# Ionic/Angular/Capacitor - Service worker registration failed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, service-worker, capacitor

I have a problem with ServiceWorker in Ionic 5 (Angular+Capacitor) app.
I have added the service worker to my app by

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

After I build it `ionic build --prod`, go to www directory and use `http-server -p 8080` everything is fine and service worker is working.

After that I use `npx cap copy` and I am building app on my device by using Android Studio.
And in this case I can see an error:

```
main-es2015.b31a6be113e928f57737.js:1 Service worker registration failed with: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/') with script ('http://localhost/ngsw-worker.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
```

Comment: I think it happens because service workers can only be loaded via https, and capacitor runs on `http://localhost/`

Comment: There is a solution here, but it is for android 24+ only : https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1655#issuecomment-579229390